# I can't understand "How important a part of your week are your free-time activities?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, questions

I am not a native English speaker. I got a question in one of my English language test exam. The question is

> How important a part of your week are your free-time activities?

What is exactly the question looking for? Please translate this into a simple form.

Comment: How important is your leisure activity compared to the rest of your week?

Comment: But how could I compare an activity (here free-time activity) with a whole week? I can compare one activity to another. Like I can compare swimming with ski diving because they are in same category. On the other hand, I can compare between days in a week like Monday and Wednesday. Could you please explain?

Comment: They want to know how much time you spend doing leisure activities and how much you value it as part of your week.

Comment: It is an oddly worded question.  The "parts" of the week referred to would be the way you spend your time.  How important is the time you spend on free-time activities compared to the time you spend on other activities such as work, sleep etc?

Comment: It's awkardly worded, but the kind of answer it is looking for is _a very important part (of my week)_ or _not a very important part_.

Answer (score 1):

The structure is: **"how" + <adj> + "a" + <noun>**

We use it to specify the intended context or framework for the answer. In your example, it roughly means, "How important are your free-time activities **as a part of your week** or **in the context of your week**?

It would be a different question to ask, "How significant **a stress relief** are your free-time activities?" or "How much of **a mental heath benefit** are your free-time activities?"

If you asked only, "How important are your free-time activities?", you might get a very wide-ranging answer, rather than the specific context of "your week".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence could be rephrased as follows:

> How important is it for you to have a part of your week for your
>   free-time activities?

or

> ...to have *time* for your free-time activities?

I'm not a native speaker of English, too, so I may be wrong :) I have found an answer to the question on the internet:

> **Examiner**: How important a part of your week are your free-time
>   activities?
>
> **Candidate**: Actually, **not really that** important. Perhaps if I was
>   working, my time off would be **the most** important part of the week in
>   some ways, but because I'm a student, I don't so much feel the need to
>   let my hair down at the weekends. I enjoy most of the time I'm
>   studying, too. It's not like doing a stressful job.

The candidate's answer words "not really that", "the most" suggest that the question is about *the level of importance*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already saw that answer on the internet. The answer is clear but not the question.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence in question looks a little tricky. To help you see its meaning easily, I'm going to try a couple of sentence changes.

> Free-time activities are an important part.

This sentence can be changed into a question below.

> How important a part are free-time activities?

This question is asking your judgment on the importance of the activities.
So, if you add words for details, you will get the sentence in your question.

> How important a part /of your week/ are /your free-time activities?

I hope this helps you grasp the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure that your first two sample "sentences" actually clarify anything because they aren't complete.

Comment: They are just samples or preliminary sentences to go to the final one. I arbitrarily constructed them to show in what process the question was created according to my understanding. So, they may be incomplete in terms of meaning.